# Как сохранить результат выбора user-а в cookie

Tags: html, jquery, css, cookie

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.floating').click(function(evt){
     evt.preventDefault();
     $('.link').text(event.target.textContent);
    
    });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
 width: 1180px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
}

.elem {
 margin-top: 14px;
 width: 480px;
 height: 310px;

}
.title {
 margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
 padding-top: 15px;
 position: relative;
}
.link {
 margin-left: 13px;
}
.regions {
 height: 50px;
 display: inline-block;
}
.floating {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 10px;
 line-height: 0.4;
 width: 20px;

}
a.floating {
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 24%;
}
a.floating:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
}
.otherregion {
 margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
 padding-top: 15px;
}
.edit {
 border:1px solid #9E9E9E;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    background: #FFF;
    width: 90%;
    height: 23px;
}
form {
 margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
.formtext {
 margin: 0px;
 padding-top: 2px;
}
.top {
 margin-left: 13px;
 margin-right: 38px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
 <a class="link" href="#">Науки</a>
 <div class="elem">
  <p class="title">Выберите свою науку</p><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg close" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <div class="regions"> 
   <a class="floating" href="#">Математика</a>
   <a class="floating" href="#">Арт</a>
   <a class="floating" href="#">Технологии</a>
   <a class="floating" href="#">Психология</a>
   <a class="floating" href="#">Нейробиология</a>
   <a class="floating" href="#">Инженерия</a>
  </div>
  <p class="otherregion">Или выберите другой:</p>
  <form>
   <input class="edit" type="text" name="add" placeholder="Начните вводить название">
  </form>
</div>
```

Всем привет.Как сохранить результат в cookie к примеру есть такой блок в котором находится 6 областей науки при каждом клике на одном из них основной элемент(класс которой title ) меняется . как сохранить результат того элемента на которой кликнул user  в cookie чтобы когда он перезагружает страницу или закрывает браузер результат не пропадал.

Comment: Самый простой способ использования кук - использовать localstorage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Общая функция Cookie() для js:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.floating').click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    $('.link').text(event.target.textContent);
    Cookie().set('science', event.target.textContent);
  });
});

function Cookie()
{
  return {
    get: function( name )
    {
      var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp("(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"));

      return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
    },
    set: function( name, value, options )
    {
      options = options || {};

      var expires = options.expires;

      if (typeof expires == "number" && expires) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + expires * 1000);
        expires = options.expires = d;
      }

      if (expires && expires.toUTCString) {
        options.expires = expires.toUTCString();
      }

      value = encodeURIComponent(value);

      var updatedCookie = name + "=" + value;

      for (var propName in options) {
        updatedCookie += "; " + propName;
        var propValue = options[propName];
        if (propValue !== true) {
          updatedCookie += "=" + propValue;
        }
      }

      document.cookie = updatedCookie;

      return null;
    },
    delete: function( name )
    {
      Cookie().set(name, '', {expires: -1});

      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
 width: 1180px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
}

.elem {
 margin-top: 14px;
 width: 480px;
 height: 310px;

}
.title {
 margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
 padding-top: 15px;
 position: relative;
}
.link {
 margin-left: 13px;
}
.regions {
 height: 50px;
 display: inline-block;
}
.floating {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 10px;
 line-height: 0.4;
 width: 20px;

}
a.floating {
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 24%;
}
a.floating:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
}
.otherregion {
 margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
 padding-top: 15px;
}
.edit {
 border:1px solid #9E9E9E;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    background: #FFF;
    width: 90%;
    height: 23px;
}
form {
 margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
.formtext {
 margin: 0px;
 padding-top: 2px;
}
.top {
 margin-left: 13px;
 margin-right: 38px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
 <a class="link" href="#">Науки</a>
 <div class="elem">
  <p class="title">Выберите свою науку</p><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg close" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <div class="regions"> 
   <a class="floating" href="#">Математика</a>
   <a class="floating" href="#">Арт</a>
   <a class="floating" href="#">Технологии</a>
   <a class="floating" href="#">Психология</a>
   <a class="floating" href="#">Нейробиология</a>
   <a class="floating" href="#">Инженерия</a>
  </div>
  <p class="otherregion">Или выберите другой:</p>
  <form>
   <input class="edit" type="text" name="add" placeholder="Начните вводить название">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь