# Как при выборе темы оформления сохранять выбор через cookie?

Tags: javascript, css

У меня есть простой сайт и на нём я хочу предоставить юзерам возможность менять темы оформления, к примеру есть три файла:

```
light.css
dark.css
yellow.css
```

Все три файла имеют разные стили, которые меняют оформление сайта. Создаю список:

```
<ul>
<li><a>Светлый стиль</a></li>
<li><a>Тёмный стиль</a></li>
<li><a>Жёлтый стиль</a></li>
</ul>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать путём клика на ссылки смену дизайна, при этом чтобы выбор сохранялся при перезагрузке страницы и при переходе на другие. Как данный функционал возможно реализовать?

Comment: Без сервера, лучше уж использовать **localStorage**

Comment: да мне бы хоть с localstorage но чтобы работало...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данное решение написано на **jQuery**, с использованием **localStorage**

Для начала сделаем вёрстку в качестве меню

```
<!-- это в head -->
<link id="style" href="" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- это в удобное местое -->
<ul id="changeColor">
  <li data-style="light">Светлый</li>
  <li data-style="dark">Тёмный</li>
  <li data-style="knight">Рыцарь</li>
</ul>
```

Атрибут `data-style` должен быть уникален и совпадать с названием `.css` файла.
Это не обязательно, конечно, но так скрипт будет короче :)

Далее переходим к сценарию, тут ориентируйтесь по комментариям

```
// Изменение цвета и сохранение
$('#changeColor').on('click', 'li', function(){
  let style = $(this).data('style'); // Получим в переменную значение выбранного стиля

  ChangeStyle(style); // Выполняем функцию
});

// "загрузка" цвета
$(document).ready(function(){
  let loadStyle = localStorage.getItem('changeColor'); // Получим значение из localStorage
  if(loadStyle) ChangeStyle(loadStyle); // выполним функцию, если в localStorage что-то есть
});


// Функция для сохранения стиля
function ChangeStyle(style) {
  localStorage.setItem('changeColor', style); // сохраняем значение в localStorage
  $('#style').attr('href', '/'+style+'.css'); // меняем стили
}
```

Comment: Сначала пытался так подключить стили: <link rel="stylesheet" src="css/dark.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" src="css/light.css"/> Не вышло.
                                                   
 
Затем вот так: 
<link id="style" href="css/darl.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link id="style" href="css/light.css" rel="stylesheet"> Но тоже не дало результатов. 

<link id="style" href="" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: в общем абсолютно никакого результата нет...

Comment: @МихаэльВейк, прошу прощения, ошибку допустил, я поправил.

Comment: @СЫРок2513, я что-то не так делаю...

Comment: вот ссылка на Скрипку: https://jsfiddle.net/milanwake/680haL5u/6/

Comment: @МихаэльВейк, начнём с того, что ваш сайт недоступен и "взять" с него css файлы не получается. Ещё момент, что вы уже подключили стили. Свяжитесь со мной, объясню подробнее - [ссылка](https://vk.com/cbipok2513)

Comment: Хорошо, сёдня напишу. Спасибо за то что помогаете. :)

Answer (score 1):

Создаем кнопки в **html**

```
<input value="Светлая" onclick="light()" type="button">
<input value="Темная" onclick="dark()" type="button">
<input value="Рыцарь" onclick="knight()" type="button">
```

Потом в **html** файле в котором у тебя эти кнопки должен быть подключен `css` файл например со светлой темой. Создай `js` файл и подключи его к файлу где ты создал кнопки и где у тебя подключена светлая тема. К тегу которым ты подключал `css` добавляешь `id`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="light.css" id="theme">
```

В js пишешь:

```
var css 
css = document.getElementById("theme");
function light(){
   css.href = "light.css";
}
function dark(){
   css.href = "dark.css";
}
function knight(){
   css.href = "knight.css";
}
```

Comment: А что будет после перезагрузки страницы?

Comment: будет светлая тема, для того чтобы была тема которую поставил пользователь нужно давать каждому пользователю какой-то id или еще что-то и записывать что пользователь с каким-то id поставил какую-то тему

Comment: @Air, в игру вступят cookie, про которые Antonio скорее всего забыл ))

Comment: да или так тоже можно

Comment: @Deonis, я бы реализовал это с помощью `localStorage`.....

Comment: @Air, согласен.

Comment: @Antonio, сижу голову ломаю, какого рода должен быть стиль `Рыцарь`...  Ну у  тя и фантазия...)))

Comment: это наверно что-то среднее между светлой и темной с добавлениями готических ноток

Comment: если у вас есть вариант с сохранением в localstorage, чтобы сохранять выбор темы юзеру, поделитесь пожалуйста...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/713438/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-user-%D0%B0-%D0%B2-cookie  это может помочь

Comment: у меня такое ощущение что то что мне нужно вообще нереально сделать)))